# Nuget restore exception when deleting subproject

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I currently have a project in dotnet that has several different projects within it. I am attempting to move out one of the projects to a separate repo and replace it with a git submodule. The issue I'm having is how to remove the package from the original repo. I can delete the directory of the package and I updated the dirs.proj to not contain those proj files.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.Build.Traversal">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectFile Include="Proj1\dirs.proj" />
    <ProjectFile Include="Proj2\dirs.proj" />
    ...
    // Removed this line <ProjectFile Include="ProjBeingMovedToNewRepo\dirs.proj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

However, when I try to build the resulting solution (msbuild dirs.proj), I get the following exception:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.RestoreEx.targets(19,5): error :
> The project file could not be loaded. Could not find a part of the path
> 'D:\git\Networking-Tycoon\src\ProjBeingMovedToNewRepo\ProjBeingMovedToNewRepo.csproj'.  D:\git\Networking-Tycoon\src\ProjBeingMovedToNewRepo\ProjBeingMovedToNewRepo.csproj [D:\git\Networking-Tycoon\dirs.proj]

It isn't clear to me exactly why the nuget restoreEx targets is trying to pull that project that was removed or where I can update those settings. I tried to disable nuget auto restore and to clean the solution before building but so far have not had luck.

One other note is that the project that is being removed is still being referenced in the project elsewhere (I was planning on referencing the submodule for those later) but wanted to see if there was something more simple I was missing first. What would be the steps that would need to be taken to remove a project like this generally?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, first close the solution.
Then goto `Tools`, `Nuget package manager`, `Package Manager Settings`.

Then `Clear all Nuget cache`.

That should clear the problem.